# GetResponse throws 400 Bad request

Tags: c#, .net

Getting 400 bad Request When trying to get the Response from my HTTPS post request. Here is my code:

```
try
{
    var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://coupons.valassis.eu/capi/directPrint/"+offerID);
    httpWebRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName,Password);
    WebHeaderCollection myWebHeaderCollection = httpWebRequest.Headers;
    myWebHeaderCollection.Add("Authorization: Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(httpWebRequest.Credentials.ToString())));

    myWebHeaderCollection.Add("x-valassis-country-code: uk");
    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
    httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/json";
    httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        string json = "[{ \"consumerId\": \"000000000000001\", \"remoteConsumerId\": \"000000000000001\" , \"Barcode\": \"Itf: 04910033400000000000000001,Ean13:ccode\", \"Type\": \"j\", \"returnUrl\": \"http://www.durex.co.uk\",\"CouponDescription\" : \"Coupon For:\"" + this.FirstName + " " + this.SurName + "\" }]";

        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        streamWriter.Write(json);
        streamWriter.Flush();
        streamWriter.Close();

        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        using (Stream streamReader =httpResponse.GetResponseStream())
        {
            using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(streamReader))
            {
                var result = r.ReadToEnd();    

            }
        }
    }        
}
catch (WebException e)
{

}
```

Any one knows what might be the problem? or How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON string that you create is invalid, as the CouponDescription property contains an odd number of quotes.

If i run this....

```
    var FirstName = "Joe";
var SurName = "Bloggs";
var json = "[{ \"consumerId\": \"000000000000001\", \"remoteConsumerId\": \"000000000000001\" , \"Barcode\": \"Itf: 04910033400000000000000001,Ean13:ccode\", \"Type\": \"j\", \"returnUrl\": \"http://www.durex.co.uk\",\"CouponDescription\" : \"Coupon For:\"" + FirstName + " " + SurName + "\" }]";
```

I get...

```
[{ "consumerId": "000000000000001", "remoteConsumerId": "000000000000001" , "Barcode": "Itf: 04910033400000000000000001,Ean13:ccode", "Type": "j", "returnUrl": "http://www.durex.co.uk","CouponDescription" : "Coupon For:"Joe Bloggs" }]
```

Look at the CouponFor value, the quotes are not closed.

Tools like [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) and [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) are very useful for validating code snippets in these scenarios