# HttpWebRequest GET throwing 400 bad request

Tags: c#, asp.net, get, httpwebrequest

I have an application which is calling an GET API for getting some reports.
Here is my code

```
 HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = null;     
 HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = null;

myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://cybersource.com/DownloadReport/2015/11/04/profile/TransactionDetailReport.xml");

myHttpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
myHttpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'";

string authInfo = "username:password";
authInfo = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(authInfo));
myHttpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + authInfo);

myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
```

I went through plenty of articles and did lot of changes here and there but still i am getting `400 bad request`

Just for my curiosity I used a wrong username and password but still I am getting the same error `400 bad request`

What is missing or wrong in my request?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/692342/net-httpwebrequest-getresponse-raises-exception-when-http-status-code-400-ba

Comment: Possible to duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23054960/getresponse-throws-400-bad-request

Comment: No, It doesn't help because the error stream shows me "something went wrong"

Comment: @KaushikMaheta they both are completely different. Before posting this question i had already gone through that post.

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with your request, your GET API require more information e.g header to process the request. You can find the general causes for the error from here http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E400.html